# How to translate "I ride a bike to exercise." English to German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Google translate isn't satisfying my translation needs. Does anyone know how to translate "I ride a bike to exercise" to German? Is "Ich fahre mit dem Fahrrad für üben" correct? What about "Ich fahre mit dem Fahrrad zu üben"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use **üben** here. That is because *üben* means practising your skill rather than working out. You can ride a bike, can't you? So, use **trainieren** instead.

And German speakers love nouns. That is why the verb *trainieren* is turned into a noun here:

> Ich fahre **zum Trainieren** Fahrrad.

Or, to emphasize on *trainieren*:

> **Zum Trainieren** fahre ich Fahrrad.

Comment: Even if "üben" were correct (if the sentence were about riding a bike in order to practise ridiing a bike) if would have to be **zum Üben**:

Comment: So wie ich *to exercise* verstehe geht es dabei nicht darum, ein besserer Radfahrer zu werden, sondern den Körper in Bewegung zu halten. Einen eingängigen deutschen Begriff kenne ich dafür nicht, vielleicht würde man „für die Fitness“ sagen.

Comment: @CarstenS Ist "trainieren" deutsch genug?

Comment: @tofro, meiner Meinung nach liegt „trainieren“ inhaltlich leicht daneben. Das erscheint mir auf spezifischere Leistungsverbesserung ausgelegt. Aber vielleicht reden die jungen Leute anders als ich ;)

Comment: @CarstenS wir kennen eben "üben" (ein (noch-)Nichtkönner will was können und übt) und "trainieren" (ein "professioneller" Könner will besser werden und trainiert) - Für den "Amateur" haben wir keinen Begriff. Wenn man aber sieht, mit welcher verbissenen Professionalität selbst Amateur-Radfahrer seit Neuerem unterwegs sind, finde ich, passt "trainieren" sehr gut und wird auch für Dinge genutzt, zu denen der Amerikaner "workout" sagen würde.

Comment: @tofro, sicher gibt es Amateure, die trainieren. (Wir könnten jetzt diskutieren, dass Leistungssport nicht nur den Hochleistungssport umfasst ) Aber das ist in meinem Verständnis nicht *to exercise*. Letzteren Begriff erwarte ich eher von Leuten, deren Ziel ist, ihr Gewicht zu kontrollieren. Natürlich gibt es Übergangsbereiche. Wenn man „Training“ näher bestimmt, passt es wieder. Moderates Ausdauer- oder Krafttraining kann gemeint sein.

Comment: Und *üben* ist nicht vollständig von *trainieren* verdrängt worden (siehe *Übungsleiter*), bräuchte hier aber die Angabe, was geübt wird.

Comment: Trotz allem ist die Antwort nicht falsch 